# Pointer to Data Buffer in C STM32

Tags: arrays, buffer, stm32

I'm fairly new to C and have following question.

I want to transmit data through I2C on STM 32 and the command is

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint16_t DevAddress, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout);
```

EDIT1: on each array element there is 8 bit count

This means that the data is of 8bits or 1byte.
But in code I've found that an array of 8bytes has been sent using the above command.
Can anyone help and explain how byte data is sent on 8 bit size.

```
TxFrame[0]=0_AnalogCntIn8[HI];

TxFrame[1]=0_AnalogCntIn8[LO];

TxFrame[2]=1_AnalogCntIn8[HI];

TxFrame[3]=1_AnalogCntIn8[LO];

TxFrame[4]=2_AnalogCntIn8[HI];

TxFrame[5]=2_AnalogCntIn8[LO];

TxFrame[6]=3_AnalogCntIn8[HI];

TxFrame[7]=3_AnalogCntIn8[LO];

HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c2,DAC_ID,TxFrame,8,100);
```

Comment: You need to learn basics. What is bit, what is byte etc etc. uC programming without this knowledge is not possible.

Comment: Its not about basics. U didn't get the question. Anyways I got answer. Thanks for taking time to comment. Its  the I2C HAL handler which handles the frame.

Comment: Read the HAL documentation. Everything is explained there.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Its the HAL handler of I2C which keeps on incrementing according to array and size we enter in the I2C command.

```
hi2c->pBuffPtr++;

      hi2c->XferCount--;
      hi2c->XferSize--;
```